# Rails – Change View Language Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have a rails project that previously was written using ERB views. I'm slowly converting the project to HAML through a process of creating a duplicate for each view as I start on it, building the HAML view to parity (with changes based on a new UI framework), and then deleting the old ERB view. The problem with this process is that rails favors the ERB view files, so I have to either rename the old view file or wait until I delete it to see the new one rendered.

While I don't consider it good practice to ship the code to production with duplicate view files for the same rendering format, this got me thinking about the process of choosing a view file: Is there a priority defined globally somewhere I could change to prefer HAML files if present in a project? How does rails choose which view file to render from?

Comment: I think [ActionView::Template::Handlers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb) is in charge of the lookup and the handlers have priority in the order they were registered or maybe its even just alphabetical...

Comment: The actual glob used to find the templates is found at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L19

Comment: @max, it seems to be the order it's registered, not alphabetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers are prioritized in the order they are registered. You can re-register a handler so it's prioritized last. For example to move ERB to last priority:

```rb
ActionView::Template.unregister_template_handler(:erb)
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(
  :erb, ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB.new)
```

To do the same with haml:

```rb
ActionView::Template.unregister_template_handler(:haml)
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(
  :haml, Haml::RailsTemplate.new)
```

More generally, if you search through a gem for `register_template_handler`, then you'll likely find the handler you need to register.

Tested in Rails 7.0